# Xcode Archive Build, Adhoc builds, and new devices

Tags: xcode, ios, adhoc

I use Xcode's "Build and Archive" feature to create an .ipa file that I can share with my testers, makes Adhoc distribution much easier.

My question - when I get a new "tester" (device) . . . is it just a matter of adding the device to the provisioning portal and including that device in the adhoc provisioning profile . . . or do I also have to re-download the provisioning profile, replace the provisioning profile in Xcode, and do the "Build and Archive" over again (for the App to work on the new device)?

I've always been assuming I had to do the latter, but just making sure.  It is a real hassle having to do that everytime I get a new tester.

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll certainly need to download the provision profile after you modify it, but you shouldn't have to rebuild the app. When you go to share the app with someone, Xcode offers to re-sign it and lets you choose the profile you want to use.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info.  Guess the notion that the App could somehow "phone home" to see if it had an updated provisioning profile was somewhat of a fantasy on my part :)